# Redirect with querystring

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a certain situation where the ActionResult method in a controller needs to do a Redirect if a Returnurl is provided.

However, how can I append a querystring to that and still use:

return Redirect(url) ?

everytime I do this, I always get a security exception that the request had a potentially dangerous value (the ampersand or even the question mark).

Answer (score 4):

Try this,filling in the name of the action and controller as appropriate:

```
System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary rvd = new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary();
foreach(string key in HttpContext.Request.QueryString.AllKeys)
{
    rvd.Add(key, HttpContext.Request.QueryString[key]);
}

return RedirectToAction("MyAction", "MyController", rvd);
```

Comment: That wouldn't work because this wouldn't be a RedirectToAction - just a pure MVC Redirect

Comment: Are you trying to redirect to a non-mvc url?

Comment: not quite. whilst it is within the MVC site, there will be a redirect to different areas depending on the returnUrl passed into the page. THAT is the url I want to redirect to after the action is "completed". Please see my answer below this comment (answer to be made tomorrow) - I used Url.Content in conjunction with the returnUrl and also the querystring I wanted to pass along with it.

Answer (score -1):

forgot - I used Url.Content and now it works just fine.

return Redirect(Url.Content(model.ReturnUrl + otherPotentialQueryStringHere)